# EXCEL - Replace function | Replace value from one column to replace with other column value

Tags: excel, replace

Input should be like,

| schema name | schema value |
| --- | --- |
| ps_din_ghr_${hiveoff:suffix} | post |

and output should be like below in new coulmn:

| schema name |
| --- |
| ps_din_ghr_post |

i want to replace after $ part with the value from the side column.

please let me know how to execute this using excel. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT : For English users replace ; by , in the formula*

You can use `SEARCH` to get the position of the $ and `REPLACE` everything after it.

For example with schema name in column A and schema value in column B -> result in column C.

To find the $ you need to use `SEARCH("$";A2)` it will give you the position.
Then you can count the number of characters to replace after the "$" by substracting the position to the length of the schema name with `LEN()`. (+1 to get the last char)

Then you can combine everything :

```
=REPLACE(A2;SEARCH("$";A2);LEN(A2)-SEARCH("$";A2)+1;B2)
```

Result in my Excel :

[image: Excel example]

Comment: =REPLACE(A2,SEARCH("$",A2),LEN(A2)-SEARCH("$",A2)+1,B2)    this is working now. actually i was using ; instead of , and hence the issue. Thank you @VirussInside

Comment: Yeah I live in Switzerland so I use Excel in french hence the ;